# How do you scroll the amount of loopcuts/bevel segments in edit mode without having to change the middle button to scroll?

Tags: shortcut

I had a question regarding how you scroll loop cuts and bevel segments with a graphics tablet, specifically a Wacom in this case.

My buttons are set to middle click and right click but to scroll the amount of loop cut and bevel segments, I have to change my middle click to scroll to make it work.
Changing to scroll also loses my middle click functionality however which is crucial to navigating in my scene.

When I have it set to middle click, I can only move where my loopcut is going to come, it doesn't activate any functions when holding the button.

**To keep the question specific:** *How do you scroll the amount of loop cut in edit mode without having to change the middle button to scroll or purchasing a 3 buttoned pen for a tablet?*

Comment: you can simply use "+" and "-"

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone! Those are indeed useful solutions. For now I will type in the number but this is unfortunately hardcoded in Blender 2.90.0 Beta. I hope it gets fixed one day!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Number or Numpad buttons to control the amount of loop cuts. Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then enter a number.

Answer (score 4):

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, you can use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to **increase** and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to **reduce** the number of loop cuts. Using this you can adjust the amount to fit your needs dynamically, while entering a number can be faster if the amount of cuts needed is known.

**Updated:**
The <kbd>Num +</kbd> and <kbd>Num -</kbd> as @moonboots mentioned and the above mentioned <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> work for me in **Blender version 2.83.3**, which should be the *version** used if you do not work with the experimental ones.

**version used currently as it's the stable and also LTS version at the time of this post.*

Answer (score 0):

According to Vaughan Ling:
unfortunately this is hardcoded in blender so can't be changed.  I usually type in the number of cuts or just scroll my mouse :P

source:
https://twitter.com/Heavypoly/status/1287449957859901440